# Will SE.Redis have a cache locally?

Tags: .net, performance, redis, stackexchange.redis

I measure my app's performance. We are using SE.Redis to server our customer WebApi query.

My app typically will be cold at night as my workload only happen during working hour.
However, I found that my app continues holding a big chunk of memory even after being idle of several hours. (<1% CPU usage but have consistent 1G memory usage).

I use the perf insight to see what happen and It is interesting that looks like SE.Redis still have a lot of HashEntry.

I am wondering why those HashEntry were not being release after hours of idle time.

Below is the screenshot.

[image: P]

Add the screenshot for the caller of Redis Hashentry.
[image]

screenshot for the managed memory view when debug the proc dump file.

[image: the top 2 memory object]

[image]

Comment: In the PerfView, who is holding the references to these objects? You can navigate the memory graph.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda add the screenshot for who is caller.